# Go Template compare if string ends in or contains another string

Tags: go, go-templates

The eq function allows for comparing if two strings are equal

```
{{if eq .Name "MyName"}}
```

Is there a way to test if a string ends in (or contains) another string?

Comment: Add a custom template function and use that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [function map](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#Template.Funcs) containing the relevant [string](https://godoc.org/strings) functions.

```
funcs := map[string]any{
    "contains":  strings.Contains,
    "hasPrefix": strings.HasPrefix,
    "hasSuffix": strings.HasSuffix}

tmpl := `{{if hasSuffix . ".txt"}}yes!{{end}}`
t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(funcs).Parse(tmpl))

t.Execute(os.Stdout, "example.txt") // writes yes! to standard out
```

[Run the example on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/3dxqsTHv7uo).

Some applications that use Go templates as a feature (Hugo and Helm are examples) provide these functions by default.

(h/t to mkopriva).

Comment: Thanks. How would I export it so that I can use it in the template file? And how would this look like in a template file? Would it be something like `{{if .TemplateName.TestString}}True{{else}}False{{end}}`?

Comment: @JonathanChen Use the template's [Funcs](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#Template.Funcs) method to make the functions available to the template. Call the functions using the syntax `functionName arg1 arg2` where `arg1` and `arg2` evaluate to strings.  Functions can be used anywhere a [pipeline](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Pipelines) can be used  including the condition of an `if` action.  Example: `{{if hasSuffix .Filename ".txt"}}It's a text file{{else}}it's some other kind of file{{end}}`.